Parsing GraphQL query response in Spring Boot App
I am still getting familiarize with GraphQL and have a requirement to parse a query response from the a 3rd party provider.
Using the 'HttpGraphQlClient'(webclient) I am successfully able to "post" the request and log the response, but struggling to parse it, to read the returned data.
The response structure looks like
{
  "data": {
    "trackedByIds": [
      {
        "shipment": {
          "eta": "2024-06-29T12:00:00.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "shipment": {
          "eta": "2024-07-29T12:00:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I am looking a way to retrieve the eta from below Tried "retrieve" and "execute" method of client but it is failing to property map to "entity", as looks like entity class is not defined correctly. Appreciate any help/suggestions

The response is JSON - look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/api/java/org/springframework/boot/json/JsonParser.html
